# Linq to SQL select multiple columns

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I just want to select 2 columns from a MSSQL DB using LINQ.

The SQL should be

```
select table.col1,table.col2 from table
```

I tried

```
IList<string> myResults =
(
    from data in dbconn.table
    where table.col5 == null
    select new { 
        col1=data.Id.ToString(),
        col2=data.col2
    }
).Take(20).ToList();
```

but this didn't work.

It says

```
cannot convert type  list <AnonymousType#1> to Ilist<string>
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what do you mean?  Is there an exception? Does it return nothing, or something other than you expect?

Comment: Note: your LINQ query sample/attempt does not seem consistent with your "SQL should be" statement.  Perhaps you could clarify your objective as well as the actual issue

Answer (score 11):

You are basically trying to fill a list of strings with the entries of a list of anonymous types, that won't work.

Have you tried something like this?:

```
var list = from data in dbconn.table
           where table.col5 == null
           select new { 
            col1=data.Id.ToString(),
            col2=data.col2
           }
```

Then you can easily use the entries in a loop for example

```
foreach(var element in list) {
//...
}
```

Or like a list

```
list.Take(20).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, a list of strings (`List<string>`) can only have one single string in an element not two (what you are trying to do here) changing the type to var would fix your exception but not sure if that is the solution you want.

```
var myResults =
(
    from data in dbconn.table
    where table.col5 == null
    select new { 
        col1=data.Id.ToString(),
        col2=data.col2
    }
).Take(20).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can select multiple fields using linq Select as shown above in various examples this will return as an Anonymous Type. If you want to avoid this anonymous type here is the simple trick.

```
var items = myResults.Select(f => new [] { f.Col1, f.Col2 }).SelectMany(item => item).Distinct();
```

I think this solves the problem