# C# Linq SQL select Multiple columns to List

Tags: c#, sql, linq, list

Hi I want to select 4 columns form DB then select to a List

```
public struct keyData
{

    public int pid;
    public int sid;
    public string proid;
    public string title;
}
```

```
Entities dbconn = new Entities();
List<keyData> temRes = (
    from viewData in dbconn.vw1
    join hData in dbconn.tableH
    on new { pid= (int)viewData.pid, proid= viewData.proid}
    equals new { pid= (int)hData .pid, proid= hData .proid}
    into joinSet
    from joinUnit in joinSet.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where joinUnit == null
    select new { pid= (int)viewData.pid, sid= (int)viewData.sid, proid= viewData.proid, Title=viewData.Title }
    ).ToList();
```

then it says:

Error   3   Cannot implicitly convert

```
type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>'
```

to `'System.Collections.Generic.List<hl.Program.keyData>'`

thanks

using MarcinJuraszek 's idea

it gives me :

```
Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities
```

Answer (score 5):

That's because your quere return an anonymous type objects. Change it to return `keyData` instances instead:

```
    List<keyData> temRes = (
        from viewData in dbconn.vw1
        join hData in dbconn.tableH
        on new { pid= (int)viewData.pid, proid= viewData.proid}
        equals new { pid= (int)hData .pid, proid= hData .proid}
        into joinSet
        from joinUnit in joinSet.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where joinUnit == null
        select new keyData() { pid= (int)viewData.pid, sid= (int)viewData.sid, proid= viewData.proid, Title=viewData.Title }
        ).ToList();
```

The difference is in `select` clause. I've added your class name after `new` keyword.

Comment: then it give me :   Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.

Comment: Do you have parameterless constructor defined for `keyData` class?

Comment: @BennyAe try adding an `empty` parameterless constructor to your `keyData` structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
Entities dbconn = new Entities();
List<keyData> temRes = (
    from viewData in dbconn.vw1.ToList()
    join hData in dbconn.tableH.ToList()
    on new { pid= (int)viewData.pid, proid= viewData.proid}
    equals new { pid= (int)hData .pid, proid= hData .proid}
    into joinSet
    from joinUnit in joinSet.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where joinUnit == null
    select new { pid= (int)viewData.pid, sid= (int)viewData.sid, proid= viewData.proid,  Title=viewData.Title }
    ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

As it was said you must return `keyData` instances instead of anonimous type https://stackoverflow.com/a/19529805/1034373. But struct can't have an explicit parameterless constructor so you must either change keyData type to class or add a counstructor

```
public struct keyData
{
    public keyData(int pid, int sid, string proid, string title)
    {
         this.pid = pid;
         this.sid = sid;
         this.proid = proid;
         this.title = title;
    }
    public int pid;
    public int sid;
    public string proid;
    public string title;
}
```

and write code like this

```
List<keyData> temRes = (
    from viewData in dbconn.vw1
    join hData in dbconn.tableH
    on new { pid= (int)viewData.pid, proid= viewData.proid}
    equals new { pid= (int)hData .pid, proid= hData .proid}
    into joinSet
    from joinUnit in joinSet.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where joinUnit == null
    select new { pid= (int)viewData.pid, sid= (int)viewData.sid, proid= viewData.proid, Title=viewData.Title }
    ).ToList().Select(x => new keyData(x.pid, x.sid, x.proid, x.title)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have answered similar question here.You can simply do this using SELECT and SELECTMANY
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27755340/2764258

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. The normal procedure would be cast a close vote (duplicate) but I think you haven't got enough points for that yet. By the way, your answer to the other question does not apply here.