# Select multiple columns in AnonymousType query.ToArray?

Tags: c#, json, linq, entity-framework

Beg pardon if this is listed somewhere already but I'm apparently failing to word this properly in a Google search and while I've found similar, nothing addresses the `ToArray` part of what I need (which is where I'm having a problem)...

Given the following code:

```
return Json(string.Join(",", (from EducationCourse in db.Courses 
    join EventsPackageCourse in db.PackageCourses on EducationCourse.CourseID equals EventsPackageCourse.CourseID
    join EventsPackage in db.Packages on EventsPackageCourse.PackageID equals EventsPackage.PackageID
    where EventsPackage.EventID == eventID
    select EducationCourse.Name).ToArray<string>()),
JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Return type of the method is `JsonResult`

**How can I modify the select  for multiple columns similar to the following *while converting it to an array*:**

```
...(etc)...
select ( new { EducationCourse.Name, EvenetsPacakgeCourse.StartDate, EventsPacakageCourse.EndDate})).ToArray<string()),
....
```

As I have it written (as per above), it generates an error: 
`'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' does not contain a definition for 'ToArray' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.ToArray<TSource>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>)' has some invalid arguments.`

**Also, if someone would be awesome enough to tell me, what would be an adequate google wording for this because googling the error isn't getting me anything that appears to be very relevant.**

Edit: Now that I've actually submitted the question, SO is showing me a sidebar link that explains what's going on and why and addresses comments by both Luizgrs and Servvy:

[Linq to SQL select multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19106058/linq-to-sql-select-multiple-columns?rq=1)

Comment: Out of curiosity, you do have `using System.Linq;` at the top of the file, correct?

Comment: @krillgar If he didn't then the code would fail on the call to `Join`, not `ToArray`.  It wouldn't even get that far.

Comment: OK. I don't use the "SQL" version of LINQ, but didn't think of that. I just know that I run into the same "does not contain a definition for 'ToArray'" when I remove and sort my usings, then add in something that does LINQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misuing the `Controller.Json` method.

It already serializes the object you pass as parameter, so you don't need to conver it to string.

Just do this:

```
return Json((from EducationCourse in db.Courses 
    join EventsPackageCourse in db.PackageCourses on EducationCourse.CourseID equals EventsPackageCourse.CourseID
    join EventsPackage in db.Packages on EventsPackageCourse.PackageID equals EventsPackage.PackageID
    where EventsPackage.EventID == eventID
    select new { EducationCourse.Name, EvenetsPacakgeCourse.StartDate, EventsPacakageCourse.EndDate}),
JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: This is what it was. I apparently don't know as much about JSON as I thought and left the original join in place from the previous coder. He apparently didn't know as much about as was needed either. The shame is that that join and whatnot is littered throughout the project. That's going to be painful to fix. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have a sequence of anonymous types, not a sequence of strings, so you cannot specify `string` as the generic argument to `ToArray`.

Either you need to change your `select` to actually select out a `string`, or you need to remove the generic argument to `ToArray` and let the anonymous type be inferred as the generic argument.